# Select Name instead OF ID in table with ID-Ref Column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say we have 2 Tables:

```
 Table A        Table B
 - A_ID         - B_ID
 - A_Name       - A_ID
```

I need a select statement, that selects * from Table B showing the `A_NAME instead of the A_ID`.

By trying it I got the following select statement which ... doesn't work to well. It is giving me a lot of nulls, but no names.

```
SELECT B_ID, 
       (select A_NAME from TableA as A where A.A_ID = B.A_ID) as Name
FROM TableB as B
```

---

**Thanks for all your Answers**.

***The final solution:***

The shown query DOES work (even though it may be slow) and the solutions in the answers also do work.

The problem why it didn't give results for me was because of my data. On another database with the same schema all the commands work.

Comment: Original query may have some perfomance issues but it expresses exactly what you said, finds names by ids. Please check your data. Share tables DDL and SQL query to populate sample data if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT 
 B_ID, A_Name 
FROM 
 tableB B LEFT JOIN tableA A
   ON B.A_ID = A.A_ID
```

Comment: This will yield same output

Comment: Im sure this is correct code, but somehow i cant get it working for me. Is it possible that there is a difference at this point between simple SQL and TransactSQL (Microsoft) ?

Comment: @Luke If you do get `NULL`s in your Name column, this simply means that there is no matching entry for `tableB.A_ID` in the `tableA`

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with a join:

```
SELECT B.B_ID, A.A_Name 
FROM B 
INNER JOIN A 
ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID;
```

---

#### Edit:

If you want only the entries from table b you can to it with a left join, like @jarlh said:

```
SELECT B.B_ID, A.A_Name 
FROM B 
LEFT JOIN A 
ON A.A_ID = B.A_ID;
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN, to also get Table B rows without any corresponding Table A rows. (Just like the original query.)

Comment: I tried both versions but did not get it working yet, for some reason it returns me 0 rows. By the way i think you got me wrong at some point: i guess the `ON` is like a `WHERE` statement which specifies conditions. In your shown code i see `A.A_ID = B.B_ID` while what i need is `A.A_ID = B.A_ID`

Comment: @Luke a sorry you are right with your matching. I updated the code